# JQuery load callback

Tags: jquery, callback, load

I am trying to fadeOut a div and load data into it through .load and then fadeIn on the div.

I have this so far:

```
$('#nietzsche').fadeOut(function (){
    $("#nietzsche").load("power.html #nietzsche2", function(){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#nietzsche').fadeIn(2000); 
    });
});
```

But JavaScript says e.preventDefault is not defined!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't define `e` anywhere. `e` is generally a parameter to an event handler. Your function isn't an event handler, so it doesn't need to be there and wouldn't do anything anyway. You can just remove it, and it should work fine:

```
$('#nietzsche').fadeOut(function (){
    $("#nietzsche").load("power.html #nietzsche2", function(){ 
        $('#nietzsche').fadeIn(2000); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add **e like function(e)** in function try this

```
$('#nietzsche').fadeOut(function (){
    $("#nietzsche").load("power.html #nietzsche2", function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#nietzsche').fadeIn(2000); 
    });
});
```